# Verification of Pinocchio (verifiable computation)

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I am reading the [Pinocchio paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/180286/pinocchio.pdf). The calculated result $y$ is a part of the verification input, but it seems to me, the verification procedure does not utilize the result $y$. Can anyone can help me to understand this?

Comment: You should probably add a link to the paper and make it easier for readers to find this $y$ and the verification procedure in the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y$ is the values of the output wires, so it is used to compute $g_v^{v_{io}(s)}$, $g_w^{w_{io}(s)}$, and $g_y^{y_{io}(s)}$. (Remember that $c_k$ is the value of the wire with index $k$.)